# Azure VMs, Monitoring and Load Balancing

Tags: azure

I have two Windows VMs behind a load balancer with monitoring setup on both VMs. When checking the CPU utilization, I notice that the load isn't evenly balanced. Here's what I'm seeing. Does this look normal for a 24 hour period? When checking for a shorter time period, it seems like the balancing isn't even.

These are Standard B2s VMs. They're hosting an API. Looking at the most recent server requests, we're getting 600k-750k in the last 7 days. We're using the Azure Basic LB with 2 http and 2 https backend pools.

**24 Hour**
[image: 24 Hours]

**1 Hour**
[image: 1 Hour]

Comment: What load balancer are using and if it’s the Azure Load Balancer add the setup details here

Comment: Added some extra info

Comment: What session persistence is your LB configured with?

Comment: It's set to None for both Http and Https